# specify sender's name when sending email in matlab

Tags: matlab, email

I'm able to send email using matlab by using the following codes:

```
mail = 'myEmail@gmail.com>';
password = 'PASSWD';

% Set up the preferences
setpref('Internet','E_mail',mail);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.gmail.com');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username',mail);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password',password);

% The following is necessary only if you are using GMail as
% your SMTP server. 
props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class', 'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','465');
% send email
sendmail('receipient@gmail.com', 'subject', 'messsage');
```

Essentially I'm sending email using myEmail@gmail.com and I'm **able** to receive email from receipient@gmail.com. However, when I received the email, the "from" field of the email body is "myEmail". Here's the body of the original email I received:

```
Message ID  <1180952044.01475877272727.JavaMail.myUserName@myMachine>
Created at: Fri, Oct 7, 2016 at 5:54 PM (Delivered after 1 seconds)
From:   myEmail@gmail.comUsing MATLAB 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
To: receipient@gmail.com
Subject:    subject
```

I was wondering if I can change the "from field" to some user-defined names. I tried to follow the instruction here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63504-how-do-i-change-the-from-fieild-of-an-email-using-matlab-s-sendmail, however, I received the error of:

```
Error using sendmail (line 171)
Authentication failed.
```

Are there any solutions to this? Thanks!